# GitHub Repository Language

Tags: flutter, github

I'm currently doing a flutter project using VSCode.

I forgot to create repository in GitHub at the beginning.

So I created it after doing and creating some files.

I also did it using terminal of VSCode. Because when I clicked Source Control it didn't show me **Publish to GitHub** button...

### And why is that???

Now when I looked my repositories in GitHub the language is showing me is C++ (Image Below)

[image: Figure 1]

### How can I fix this?

When I go inside of this repository it shows languages like this (Figure 2)

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: this analysis is performed on the flow, so it changes as the amount of code in your repository changes. Write more code in dart then you will get more dart in statistics

Comment: @Chris okay thanks. But I didn't code anything in C++. Then why this is showing me like this?

Comment: Flutter project generates a bit of code, part of it is in C++

Answer (score 2):

Just add a .gitattributes file in your project root folder, like this:

```
*.h linguist-detectable=false
*.cc linguist-detectable=false
*.cpp linguist-detectable=false
*.kt linguist-detectable=false
*.rb linguist-detectable=false
*.swift linguist-detectable=false
*.cmake linguist-detectable=false
*.gradle linguist-detectable=false
*.json linguist-detectable=false
*.plist linguist-detectable=false
*.html linguist-detectable=false
*.xml linguist-detectable=false
*.xib linguist-detectable=false
*.storyboard linguist-detectable=false
*.manifest linguist-detectable=false
*.entitlements linguist-detectable=false
*..properties linguist-detectable=false
*.xc* linguist-detectable=false
Podfile linguist-detectable=false
CMakeLists.txt linguist-detectable=false
```

This works because Github added "overrides" to Linguist, so now users can modify the default classification of files by overriding with git attributes. See issue https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/3964, which was solved by PR https://github.com/github/linguist/pull/3807, and example given in https://github.com/github/linguist/pull/3806).

Answer (score -2):

delete windows, web, macos and linux directory in your project folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).